# How to pull random image within layout xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

Within my layout xml file I would like the 'android:src=""' to pull a random image from a 'bg' folder within drawable.

I know this can be done pragmatically but I'd like to keep it within the layout files.

Is there any way to create an array of everything in the bg folder and pull from it from within the layout xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer is no, but I can provide source code to help do it programmatically

EDIT: You need to place all the images you want to use in your drawables folder, then in bg.xml put the ones that you want to appear in the button, see the example below, goodluck!

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.stackoverflow17462606;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(getRandomImage());
    }

    private int getRandomImage() {
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
        // or set you ImageView's resource to the id
        int id = imgs.getResourceId(new Random().nextInt(imgs.length()), -1); //-1 is default if nothing is found (we don't care)
        imgs.recycle();
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
       <string-array name="random_imgs">
        <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item>@drawable/ic_settings</item>
        <!-- ... -->
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I can get the image to the same position if I do it progmatically? Currently the ImageView is within a RelativeLayout

Comment: If you provide the code, I can help you, but basically you should have the ImageView already in your layout and you are just changing the src in you code.